# Continuously read data in real time with Flask + Python

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi2

I want to read in a webapp some elements (CPU temperature, CPU usage, state of some sensors...) in real-time from my Raspberry Pi. I know Python instruction to do this, but I want to read these values (let's focus now only on CPU temperature, for example) from a PHP page in real-time, so continuously refreshing the page. I've found various methods on the internet, but there's here a SIMPLE mode to do this?

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    temp="There I'll put instructions..."
    return render_template("index.php", temp=temp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Are you using Flask or PHP?

Comment: I'm using Flask, I want PHP only for the renderer (I'm also a newbie, tell me if I'm doing wrong usage of these words :) )

Comment: It looks like you need to fetch a PHP-generated page from somewhere, parse it, and output your own page. Packages to consider are `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` (if it's a HTML page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply resolved adding `<body onload="location=''">` in the HTML code of PHP page.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a REST API using `flask` that will return sensor data upon request. Here's an example of what your server might look like:

```
@app.route('/sensor/<sensor>')
def get_sensor_data(sensor):
    sensor = sensor.lower()
    if sensor == 'cpu':
        sensor_data = cpu_sensor_data()
    elif sensor == 'ssd':
        sensor_data = ssd_sensor_data()
    # etc.

    return sensor_data
```

Your frontend would then need to make a request to an endpoint like `http://domain_name.net/cpu` and get the sensor data to display as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I want to do exactly this, but automatically... this is the question

Comment: `<script>setTimeout(update_from_rest,5)</script>` or something in your template.html